# How can I tell whether a function returns "nothing" or NULL?

Tags: php, null

Consider a function that explicitly returns `null`:

```
function nullreturn() {return null;}
$rv = nullreturn();
var_dump($rv);
var_dump(isset($rv));
var_dump(is_null($rv));
```

Which identifies as `null` -- as expected.

```
NULL
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

And consider a function with no return value -- or even a `return` statement:

```
function noreturn() {}
$rv = noreturn();
var_dump($rv);
var_dump(isset($rv));
var_dump(is_null($rv));
```

Which *also* identifies as `null`:

```
NULL
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

... is there a way to determine that `noreturn` returns "nothing" instead of `null`?

---

<sup>As to why I need this `null`/`void` distinction, I've just been trying to achieve compatibility with a previous service implementation that *did* make this distinction and which includes tests for it. But, it's *probably* not critical. I just don't want to strip away the relevant tests and hope I wasn't depending on the distinction *if I were overlooking an achievable solution*.</sup>

Comment: You can't, because (as [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)) no return value means a return of null; not unless the return void RFC is accepted for PHP 7.1

Comment: I'm more interested in what lead you to ask this question

Comment: Nothing returned will just lead to NULL being returned. Any reason why you would need to differentiate between the 2?

Comment: I'm suggest it's a `function` not `procedure`. If you remember `pascal-language`. It has two major types of subroutines - `function` that returns a typed value and `procedure` that returns nothing. It hides inside the word `function`. `sin` is math-function, `cos` is math-function - both of them returns a value. PHP doesn't have any other major types of subroutines. :).. In any case `function` is `function`, it `must` returns a value, imho. I think this text is kind of offtop .. sry :)

Comment: Do you know which functions have no return? If your function is part of a class, I'd set a variable within the class to a value you'll recognize as "no return". Assuming the two functions you're trying to differentiate are not within the same class.

Comment: To those wondering ***why -- for the love of Zeus, WHY!?***, see my edit.

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for the link. Hope you don't mind, I incorporated it into Will's answer for completeness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Not returning, and returning `NULL`, are the exact same thing. A function with no return value implicitly returns `NULL`. This applies in many languages. Sorry if this isn't the answer you're looking for, but it is reality.

The following each do the exact same thing:

```
function A() {
    return;
}

function B() {
    return NULL;
}

function C() {
}
```

See also [`return` in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php):

> Note: If no parameter is supplied, then the parentheses must be
>   omitted and NULL will be returned. Calling return with parentheses but
>   with no arguments will result in a parse error.